# Pulseaudio echo/noise-canceling module is not persisting between reboots

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, noise

My laptop microphone pics up a lot of whiney and white noise which is intolerable for my coworkers to listen to.

I have tried to follow a myriad of guides on how to enable the pulse echo/noise reduction module, like these ones:

- [How To Enable Echo / Noise Cancellation Of Microphone Input On Your Linux Desktop (PulseAudio)](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/09/how-to-enable-echo-noise-cancellation.html)
- [Disable volume auto adjust in pulseaudio “module-echo-cancel”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015327/disable-volume-auto-adjust-in-pulseaudio-module-echo-cancel)

However, settings don't persist after a reboot: when going into the "sound" menu, I can only choose my microphone input device without any noise reduction.

To make things worse, when the echo/noise cancellation module finally is loaded (just after having edited `/etc/pulse/default.pa`), the automatic gain adjustment goes nuts by turning the microphone gain up and down like a roller coaster.

In short, I (and all of my windows co-workers) would really, really, really appreciate if someone can provide me with an easy to follow guide on:

1. Enable the pulse echo/noise reduction module so that it is always on by default (also after reboots).
2. Persistently disable the automatic microphone gain, so that microphone gain can only happen if I manually adjusted through the sound settings.

My laptop is an MSI GS66 running Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Comment: I have good result with this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1284790/1138972

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for me; the input volume/gain still goes up and down (mainly up) uncontrollably. 
Can I ask, do you do "pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio --start" after every reboot in order to be able to enable noise cancellation?